# N1QL Concatenate many rows into single string

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Consider in Couchbase I have 3 documents, holding names:

Peter
Paul
Mary

Is there an easy way to turn this into a single string of Peter, Paul, Mary using N1QL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT ENCODE_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(d.name)) AS name
FROM mybucket d
WHERE d.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it again I asked a wrong question. Would you mind to help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742657/n1ql-concantenate-many-children-rows-into-single-string