# N1QL Concatenate many children rows into single string

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Consider in Couchbase I have a person database, with 3 documents:

```
Person A
    Child AA
        Grand AAA
        Grand AAB
    Child AB
        Grand ABA
        Grand ABB

Person B

Person C
    Child CA
    Child CB
        Grand CBA
```

Is there an easy way to turn this into following results using N1QL?
I am trying to display each person with their grand children displayed into strings?

```
Person A, Grand: "AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB"
Person B, Grand: ""
Person C, Grand: "CBA"
```

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON document for Person A.

Comment: The actual JSON is not person db, it is conversation db. http://jsonformatter.org/95d95b

Comment: I need to display all words into 1 string per channel. There are 3 level: channel, utterance, word just like original question person, child, grand. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT p.name AS p, ENCODE_JSON(ARRAY_AGG(g.name)) AS g
FROM person AS p LEFT OUTER UNNEST p.child AS c LEFT OUTER UNNEST c.grand AS g
GROUP BY p;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I will test it out asap